# True and False 2 sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have to input a value in column I in sheet 1  from excel and in the column "D" from sheet 2 it needs to appear true or false. If there's any value in I than it should be true in "D" otherwise "false".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `IF` should suffice, this would be in cell D1 of Sheet 2:

```
=IF(Sheet1!I1="","false","true")
```

Or a combination of `IF` and `ISBLANK`:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!I1),"false","true")
```

**Edit**:

If your sheet is called `Status` then your formula should be either:

```
=IF(Status!I1="","false","true")
```

Or:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Status!I1),"false","true")
```

Comment: It is giving me a error, saying that the formula as an error

Comment: have you renamed `Sheet1`?

Comment: Or is it called something else in Portuguese language Excel?

Comment: I changed the name of the sheet it's named "Status" and I'm using portuguese excel Change something like what?

Comment: See updated answer..